# Why on printenv I cannot see the HOSTNAME enviromental variable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, environment-variables

On my ubuntu machine where I rin the following command:

```
printenv | grep HOSTNAME
```

Shows no output whilst when I do the following on terminal:

```
echo ${HOSTNAME}
```

Output is shown. SO I wanted to know why in printenv does not shows the `HOSTNAME` environmental variable?

Answer (score 4):

Because it's not an environment variable, it's only a *shell variable* – that is, it has not been `export`ed into the environment. (Bash automatically generates this variable for use by its CLI and shellscripts, but does not export it unless you ask it to do so.)

(When you use `echo $var`, the expansion is done by Bash when interpreting the command, not by the command itself – so it has full access to variables that only exist in Bash's memory.)

The same applies also to custom variables: if you set them without using the `export` command, they only exist within the shell but are not exported into its environment. For example:

```
testone=111
export testtwo=222
echo $testone, $testtwo
printenv | grep test
```